# Increase default lock timeout in SqlCeConnection.ConnectionString

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I'm trying to increase the [`default lock timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.connectionstring.aspx) in my connection string like this:

```
strConnectionString = "Data Source=....;SSCE:Default Lock Timeout=50000;"
```

I also tried it like this

```
strConnectionString = "Data Source=....;default lock timeout=50000;"
```

But I keep getting the error, that my parameter is invalid for my connection string.
Does anybody know how this have to be implemented properly?
The connection string works fine if I remove it.

Comment: Try to lower the value maybe. Are you using SqlCeConnection class?

Comment: Did not work for me either.  And it is not a property in ConnectionBuilder.  It is not a property in SQLCommand.  I would try DbParameterCollection

Comment: Or try this  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.persistence.sqlpersistenceproviderfactory.locktimeout(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @ErikEJ Decreasing the value to i.e. 10000 seemed to do the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to lower the value maybe, it may be outside the allowed range, which I cannot see documented anywhere